# WebRTC NMS,TURN Server Deployment

Tags: webrtc

I am new on WebRTC I have some questions regarding WebRTC

1.Is there any free NMS for WebRTC?
2.If I deploy 3 TURN servers on location A,B & C
what will happen If a user on location A calls user on location C.
Or Is it a sensible decision to deploy a central TURN server for locations A,B & C.
And what are advantages and disadvantages for deploying TURN server on
a) each location
b) central TURN server for three locations..